# Chrome Extension waiting for ajax data to load before returning

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension which loads a specific page, gets some detail from it, then needs to click a button, wait for the data to load, then scrape the details, then click another button and so. The data loading is an ajax request and updates a section of the page.

```
async function processPage() {
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});

    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tab.id},
        function: processHTML,
    },
        (results) => {
            doStuffWithTheResults(results[0].result);
        
    });
}

function processHTML() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("c_carousel_button");
    
    processButton(0);
    
    let data = [];
    
    function processButton(buttonIdx) {
        buttons[buttonIdx].click();
        
        setTimeout(function() {
            const results = process()); //will read the data on the loaded elements
            data.push(results);
            
            buttonIdx++;
            
            if (buttonIdx < dateButtons.length) {
                processButtonDay(buttonIdx); //call the same function to work on the next button               
            } else {
            
            /*****
            *
            *  I WANTO RETURN data FROMHERE
            *            
            ******/
        },1000); // wait a second for the data to load after the button click
    }
    
    /* Its is returning from here before the data is loaded and processed in the code above
}
```

Because the timeout is async, it is returning bwefore this is complete. If I do a loop to wait for complete to be set, it bungs up the script and doesn;t do anything.

How can I return the data when all the processess are complete?

Comment: Your processHTML should `return new Promise(resolve => {` and then your inner code should call `resolve('your data')` e.g. inside setTimeout callback.